# Choppy video carousel animation using Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, carousel, srware-iron

I am trying to build my own video carousel with bootstrap and it is coming together except the animation between videos is really choppy, look on the right side when hitting the next button and look on the left when hitting the previous button. Why would this be?

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iHUPoSal/2/edit)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Demo looks fine to me, didn't notice any choppiness with the animation.

Comment: I've also noticed that this DEMO works perfectly fine in Chrome but in Firefox it is slow and in SRWare Iron it is really choppy

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could not find any solutions to actually fix the problem using javascript or html. Solved the problem for my own carousel by editing the images. You need to make sure they are not wider than they need to be. It seems if you use the browser to resize images (eg. because you want 2x for retina) FireFox gets choppy, even on my 5th gen. i5. Just give the images a reasonable size in the first place.